# NullPointerException from Boolean

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean

This is one for the java purists I think. I recently had an issue with a method to perform a custom parsing of String values to a Boolean. A simple enough task, but for some reason the method below was throwing a NullPointerException in the null case...

```
static Boolean parseBoolean(String s)
{
    return ("1".equals(s) ? true : ("0".equals(s) ? false : null));
}
```

The return type for the method is Boolean so why or how can a NullPointerException be thrown?
From debugging through it seems the exception is being thrown at the point where the nested in-line conditional statement evaluates to null and returns null to the outer in-line conditional, but again I can't explain why.

Eventually I gave up and rewrote the method as follows, which works as expected:

```
static Boolean parseBoolean(String s)
{
    if ("1".equals(s)) return true;
    if ("0".equals(s)) return false;

    return null;
}
```

The following code is half way between the two and also works as expected:

```
static Boolean parseBoolean(String s)
{
    if ("1".equals(s)) return true;

    return "0".equals(s) ? false : null;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice "puzzler"

Comment: @NilsH thanks for the +1, and for the solution!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This also works:

```
static Boolean parseBoolean(String s)
{
    return ("1".equals(s) ? Boolean.TRUE : ("0".equals(s) ? Boolean.FALSE : null));
}
```

So the reason you get an NPE is due to autoboxing because using `boolean` in the ternary operator causes the result of the expression to be treated as a `boolean`. And un-boxing of `null` causes an NPE.

Comment: +1 Well done. Not what one original thinks looking at the code.

Comment: Good answer @Nils - slippery little devil that one! I hadn't thought of using the `Boolean` constants.

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion? Don't return `Boolean`, return `boolean` and throw an exception:

```
static boolean parseBoolean(String s)
{
  if ("1".equals(s)) return true;
  if ("0".equals(s)) return false;

  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s + " is not a boolean value.");
}
```

Adopting an approach like the above will help avoid you accidentally referencing a null `Boolean` object.

See the [excellent answer from NilsH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233619/474189) to see why your original method is throwing an exception.

Comment: I agree. It's better to fail fast than run into an NPE later. A Boolean has it's uses though, if one needs a "tri state" solution.

Comment: This is a tri-state condition, so I really shouldn't be throwing exceptions for expected values!
Also isn't exception handling more expensive anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting but no answer tells you **why** this happens in the first place.

This has to do with the ternary expression.

The compiler interprets null as a null reference to Boolean, applies the autoboxing/unboxing rules for Boolean (on a null) => you get a NullPointerException at runtime.

Comment: @NilsH probably at the time of writing missed this part of yours. :) +1 from me.